# Check if substring exists in variable

Tags: php, twig

```
{% set x%}some string to check{% endset %}
{{ 'to' in x }}
```

will always return `0`.

In documentation I couldn't find any similar example.

**Solution**

```
{% if 'to' in x~'' %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the variable using the classic way instead of the capture mode, the code should works:

So use this:

```
{% set x='some string to check'  %}
```

instead of:

```
{% set x%}some string to check{% endset %}
```

See an example in this working [feed](https://twigfiddle.com/dwh8vx)
hope this help

Comment: Worth mentioning the reason why it doesn't work is the fact `x` will become an instance of `Twig_Markup` and the filter [`twig_in_filter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21lib%21Twig%21Extension%21Core.php/function/twig_in_filter/8.2.x) does not account for it.

Comment: thanks @DarkBee for the explanation! I can't find any reason for this behaviour

Comment: You can view the generated source of a template on twigfiddle, right hand corner. A "hack" to "solve" this issue would be to force cast the `Twig_Markup` to a string with `{% if 'to' in x~'' %}` but it looks ugly...

Comment: So basically i write ~ or i write my own comparison function/ filter ?

Comment: @Matteo i cant use the solution you proposed because enclosed in set i have ~100 lines of twig markup.

Comment: @Emanuel then go with the `x~''` solution or write a function if you feels it is too ugly. I've opened an issue about this at [github](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3037) as well.

Comment: This is now fixed as of [twig 2.11.1](https://twigfiddle.com/dwh8vx/2)